# add descriptor row over pandas df header

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I currently have a DataFrame, `df`, in the format:

```
name  age   color
John   13   purple
Alisa  15   blue
```

making it such that I can access specific columns of this DataFrame
using things like `df['name']`, `df['age']`, etc.

I'd like to add a descriptor row, to describe the column names, on top of the column header row, like so:

```
This is the customers name    This is the customer's age    This is the customer's favorite color     
name                          age                           color
John                          13                            purple
Alisa                         15                            blue
```

but I need for `df` to still have the ability be accessed using header keys like `df['age']`, `df['color']` and not be affected by this descriptor row.

I've tried `merge()`, `append()`, and `join()`, but using these functions usually result in the descriptor row being added on the same level (same row) as the column name row, as opposed to on top of it.

Any insight would be much appreciated.

**Edit:** My real DataFrame will eventually be saved as an excel file and used by other members on my team. It contains a lengthy row of about 70 complicated variables, the meanings of which are not explicit from the column keys. Column descriptions are essential for them to understand what each column represents, which is why this question is relevant for my problem.

Comment: Can you explain *why* you need it? Is it for output to Excel / CSV, or is it so that *in Python* you have the ability to store / reference meta-data?

Comment: My real DataFrame will eventually be saved as an excel file and used by other members on my team. It contains a lengthy row of about 70 complicated variables, the meanings of which are not explicit from the column keys. Column descriptions are essential for them to understand what each column represents.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely need this functionality, then you can put the original column name as the top level of the MultiIndex like this:

```
title = "This is a customer's {}"
cols = [(name, title.format(name)) for name in df.columns]
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(cols)
```

[image]

You will be able to select each column as normal like this.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to use CSV files and take advantage of the fact data can be written to CSV files sequentially. This shouldn't be a problem, as Excel can read CSV files. Here's a demo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]],
                  columns=list('ABC'))

with open('output.csv', 'w') as fout:
    fout.write('Description_A,Description_B,Description_C')
    fout.write('\n')
    df.to_csv(fout, index=False)
```

Then you can read your descriptions and data separately:

```
print(pd.read_csv('output.csv', nrows=0).columns)

Index(['Description_A', 'Description_B', 'Description_C'], dtype='object')

print(pd.read_csv('output.csv', skiprows=[0]))

   A  B  C
0  0  1  2
1  3  4  5
2  6  7  8
```